# Identifying a periodic meromorphic function as $\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, complex-integration

Let $f:\Bbb C\backslash\Bbb Z \to \Bbb C$ be a meromorphic function with the period of $2$ in the real direction, i.e. $f(z+2)=f(z)$. Each $n\in \Bbb Z$ is a simple pole such that $\text{Res}(f(z),n)=(-1)^n$. These are the only poles of $f$.

> From this information alone, is it possible to conclude that $f(z) = \frac {\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}+C$?

I know that
$\frac {\pi}{\sin{\pi z}} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n}{z-n}$
so this is certainly a possible candidate for $f$. However, I don't know if it is the only function that fits the bill.

**Edit**: Thank you for all the comments so far, I just realized that the original question has trivial answer because I forgot to mention a crucial information: $f$ is a primitive of a meromorphic function $g$ that has poles of order $2$ at each $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Taking into account Conrad's comment, would it be enough to get the conclusion provided that we assume some kind of bound for $g$ in the vertical direction?

Comment: Do you know these are the only poles of $f(z)$? From the phrasing, it seems like there could possibly be more poles, just that it is known there are simple poles at each integer. If more poles are possible, I think multiplying by some factor like $\cos(2\pi z)$ might allow variations of $f(z)$ since it preserves the orders of the poles/residues at the integers. (This might not be a perfect argument, it's just an idea to consider.)

Comment: You can always add a constant, $\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z} + C$ also satisfies these conditions.

Comment: You can add to it $C+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}p\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)$ for some polynomial $p$ with $p(0)=p'(0)=0$ and the function would still satisfy the same properties. Take a look at [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem).

Comment: So, the functions satisfying that property are of the form $g(e^{\pi iz})+\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}p\left(\frac{1}{z-n}\right)$, for $p$ some polynomial with $p(0)=p'(0)=0$ and $g$ analytic in the plane minus the origin.

Comment: another perspective on this is that $g(z)=f(z)-\frac {\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}$ is entire (poles of $f$ are assumed simple, so $f- \frac {(-1)^n}{z-n}$ is locally analytic at $n$) and periodic with period two (lots of such as noted); usually a bounding vertical condition needs to be added to give unicity (there is a classical theorem about the Gamma function in that direction) so if you assume $f$ is vertically bounded on any width $2$ strip ($|f(x+iy)| \le C, |y| \ge |y_0| >0, x \in [0,2]$ you get your unicity result up to a constant

Comment: @Conrad I'm very interested in your remark. Regarding my modified question, do you think some kind of bound for $g$ would be sufficient?

Comment: yes ; to avoid confusion let $h(z)=f(z)-\frac {\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}$; $h'$ is still entire bounded vertically (since both $f', (\frac {\pi}{\sin{\pi z}})'$ are, the first by assumption, second by inspection) and periodic with period 2, so constant; then $h$ would be degree (at most) one polynomial and periodic, hence constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $2$-periodic entire function is of the form $$g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i \pi nz}, \qquad \forall r, \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n e^{rn}=\lim_{n \to \infty} c_{-n} e^{rn}=0$$

Then $f $ is meromorphic $2$-periodic with poles at integers of order $1$ and residue $(-1)^n$ iff $f-\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$ is a $2$-periodic entire function.

> That $g$ is bounded on $\Im(z) > 1,\Re(z) \in [0,2]$ means $c_n = \lim_{y \to \infty} \frac12 \int_0^2 e^{-i \pi n (x+iy)} g(x+iy)dx= 0$ for $n< 0$,  That $g$ is bounded on $\Re(z) \in [0,2]$ means $c_n = 0$ for $n\ne  0$, ie. $g$ is constant.